# How to bind session data to gridview for shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, shopping-cart

I am not sure is this a best way but i am storing shopping cart data in Dictionary. I would like to bind data to gridview and use in aspx page.

Somehow, can we use `<%# Eval("product_id") %>` in gridview in aspx page?

**Set Dictionary**

```
public Dictionary<int, Product> products = null;
```

**Cart:**

```
products = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
```

**Reading data with this code:**

```
Cart mycart = (Cart)Session["activecart"];
            double GeneralTotal = 0; 
            foreach (int i in mycart.products.Keys)
            {
                Response.Write(mycart.products[i].product_id);
                Response.Write(mycart.products[i].product_name);
                Response.Write(mycart.products[i].product_price);
                Response.Write(mycart.products[i].product_quantity);
                Response.Write(mycart.products[i].total_price);
                GeneralTotal += mycart.products[i].total_price;
            }
            Response.Write(GeneralTotal);
```

I can read values using foreach but i want to show those data in gridview using Eval.

I have tried this code to bind gridview:

```
Cart activeCart = (Cart)HttpContext.Current.Session["activecart"];
gridview1.DataSource =  activeCart.products;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

This is only getting key, value variable from dictionary. Couldn't get specific values using `<%#Eval("custom") %>`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why you using to response.Write method. Which is not requires and your storing the product data in the dictionary value property how it will bind to Gridview. GridView will accept IList or IEnumerable to bind the data.

Comment: @RaviKumarKasim i just tried to get cart values that i want to be sure if my dictionary is works fine. That's why i used those codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Cart mycart = (Cart)Session["activecart"];
double GeneralTotal = 0; 

DataTable tempBasket = new DataTable();
DataRow rowTempBasket;
tempBasket.Columns.Add("product_id", typeof (int));
//Add the other columns  the same way

foreach (int i in mycart.products.Keys)
{
     rowTempBasket = tempBasket.NewRow();
     rowTempBasket["product_id"] = mycart.products[i].product_id;
     //Add the other columns the same way

     tempBasket.Rows.Add(rowTempBasket);
}

//Then DataBind the created table to your GridView
gridview1.DataSource = tempBasket; 
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Then you should be able to use Eval.

**EDIT**

Maybe you post the code of your ASPX page. Would help what to do about the Total.

Comment: I just tried this code seems very helpful but i don't want to create column automatically. Result is showing special column has product id and my custom column shows product_id. I just want to get value with <%#Eval("product_id")%> not automatically creating new column and show result automatically.

Comment: okay, i just set property of gridview to AutoGenerateCloumns="false"  and problem is gone. I will try with multiple products i hope this is final step.

Comment: You can name the column for the temp DataTable whatever you want. I just used the same name for association. Good idea with AutoGenerateColumns="false".